# Analyzing the convergence/iteration complexity of an algorithm with geometric convergence

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-complexity

Consider an algorithm with a convergence rate given by: `O((1-1/\kappa)^t)`.
How does one show that this gives an iteration complexity of O(\kappa*1/\epsilon)?

Setting  `O((1-1/\kappa)^t)=\epsilon` and solving for t just seems to give that t=O(log\epsilon).

Comment: Where did you see written it should be $O(\kappa/\varepsilon)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ignoring the $O(\cdot)$, which doesn't change the argument.*

You cannot get an interation complexity with an inverse linear dependence on $\varepsilon:$ that rate gives a logarithmic dependence.

Specifically, you have a convergence rate of $$
f(t) = \left(1-\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)^t$$
so to achieve an error $\varepsilon$, you need at least $T$ iterations, where
$f(T) \leq \varepsilon$, i.e.,
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)^T \leq \varepsilon
$$
which, taking the logarithm and reorganizing, leads to
$$
T \geq \log\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \cdot \frac{1}{-\log(1-\kappa^{-1})} = \Theta\!\left(\kappa\log\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)
$$
assuming $\kappa \gg 1$, along with $-\log(1-x) = \Theta(x)$ when $x\to 0$.